# JHipster: Error: In the relationship between Image and ImageType, ImageType is not declared

Tags: java, orm, relationship, jhipster, code-generation

JHipster: Error: In the relationship between Image and ImageType, ImageType is not declared.

```
entity Image {
}
enum ImageType {
   MAIN
}
relationship OneToOne {
    Image{type} to ImageType
}
```

How to implement unidirectional one to one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think instead of having unidirectional one-to-one relationship, you want `ImageType` to be a field of `Image`:

```
enum ImageType {
    MAIN
}
entity Image {
    type ImageType
}
```

If for some reason you actually want one-to-one relationship, you need to use your `enum` in an `entity`:

```
enum ImageType {
    MAIN
}
entity ImageTypeEntity {
    type ImageType
}
entity Image {
}
relationship OneToOne {
    Image{imageTypeEntity} to ImageTypeEntity
}
```